# Inserting a string into another string no library functions

Tags: c, string

I am attempting to complete a homework assignment, part of which is to design a function that inserts a string into another string. All  functions, with the exception of strlen(), are off limits to me. Specifically the problem is this: I am having trouble implementing the part of the function that "makes room" in the target string for the inserted string. Inserting the string always results in a trampling of array elements. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here? Thanks for helping me learn!

Edit: Integer n is the location in the string that I am supposed to insert the other string.

```
    void insertstring(char *str, char *ins, int n)
    {
        int i;
        int scoot=strlen(ins);
        char *p=str+n;

        for (i=strlen(str); i > n; --i) { //This is where I'm doing it wrong I think
            str[i+scoot]=str[i];          //
        }

        do {
            *p = *ins;
            ++p;
            ++ins;
        }
        while (*ins != '\0');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any specific requirements about where you must insert one string inside the other?  Did your instructor provide samples of input and expected output?  Is there a specific position in which you are supposed to insert one string inside the other?  This can significantly change how you implement it.

Comment: What is n? Can you please describe more explicity what you're supposed to do?

Comment: Oh yes. I failed to mention that. The function takes a parameter (int n) which is the location in the string that the sub-string is to be inserted.

Comment: What should happend if `str` is shorter then `n`?

Comment: OT: All those `int`s should better be `size_t`. See the type returned by `strlen()`.

Comment: @alk I suppose it wouldn't work in that case. I am not required to plan for that. No error checking required where not specifically indicated by the professor.

Comment: In case there is no restriction on `n` in relation to the length of `str` in your assignment you'd better go and cover this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have change

```
for (i=strlen(str); i > n; --i)
```

to

```
for (i=strlen(str); i >= n; --i)
```

because you have to move `str[n]` too.

The other problem is when you insert `ins`:

```
do {
        *p = *ins;
        ++p;
        ++ins;
}
while (*ins != '\0');
```

Here you copy the terminating `'\0'` from `ins` to `str` so the rest is lost. Change it to

```
while (*ins != '\0') {
        *p = *ins;
        ++p;
        ++ins;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem and I see now why a do/while loop was the wrong choice.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution uses reversing to achieve the desired result. Assume your target string, str, is composed of two blocks, AB, where A is the block before the insertion point, and B is the block after insertion point. Furthermore, assume that the string to insert, ins, is denoted by a third block C.

It can be seen that if you concatenate C to AB and then reverse B, reverse C, and reverse both B and C, you get ACB, which is the desired result. More explicitly, this is what you have after appending C to AB:

ABC

And this is what you want:

ACB

ACB can be obtained by:

- Reverse B, to get B_r (B reversed);
- Reverse C, to get C_r - at this point we have AB_rC_r;
- Reverse both B and C, that is, compute A(B_rC_r)_r, which yields ACB.

Here's the code that implements this algorithm:

```
void reverse(char *, char *, char *);
/* Insert string C between blocks AB in str */
void insertstring(char *str, char *ins, int n) {
    /* 1 - Append C to the end of str */
    int i = strlen(str);
    char *p = str+i, *q = ins;
    while ((*p++ = *q++));
    p--;
    /* 2 - Reverse C and B */
    reverse(str, str+i, p-1); /* C */
    reverse(str, str+n, str+i-1); /* B */
    /* 3 - Reverse B_rC_r */
    reverse(str, str+n, p-1);
}

void reverse(char *str, char *begin, char *end) {
    char tmp;
    while (begin < end) {
        tmp = *begin;
        *begin = *end;
        *end = tmp;
        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

And some sample code to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    void insertstring(char *, char *, int);
    char test[128] = "A string to test.";
    printf("Before: %s\n", test);
    insertstring(test, "hello!", 4);
    printf("After: %s\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

This will insert "hello!" beginning in test[4]. Here's the output:

```
$ ./test
Before: A string to test.
After: A sthello!ring to test.
```

Consider taking this approach: the code is short and elegant. This technique is described in Programming Pearls, 2nd edition, as a good way to perform vector rotation. According to the author, Brian Kernighan and P.J. Plauger used precisely this method in their Software Tools in Pascal to move lines within a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

After mentioning about `n`, update for loop as

```
for (i=n+scoot; i >= n; i--)
```

You want to move `strlen(ins)` number of character ahead from location `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with single loop,

> go to index , copy `src` content into `temp_array` and simultaneously copying `medi` into `src` 
>   once `medi` is copied completely , start putting the content of `temp_array` till it become empty

```
void insert_in_middle (char *src, char *medi, int index)
{
    int i=0, j = index, k=0;
    char temp_array[50];

    while(src[j] != '\0' ||  temp_array[k] != '\0')
    {
        temp_array[i] = src[j];
        if(medi[i] != '\0')
        {
            src[j] = medi[i];
        }
        else if(temp_array[k] != '\0')
        {
            src[j] = temp_array[k];
            k++;
        }
        i++; j++;
    }
    printf("src[%s]\n", src);
    printf("medi[%s]\n",medi);
    printf("temp_array[%s]\n",temp_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *str_ins();

int main()
{
   char *test = "Hello, world!";
   printf("%s\n",test);
   str_ins(&test,strstr(test,"world"),"my ");
   printf("%s\n",test);
}

char *str_ins(a, b, c)  // insert string c into a at point b
char **a, *b, *c;
{
   char *stemp;
   int pos = strlen(*a) - strlen(b);
   stemp = (char *) malloc(strlen(*a)+strlen(c)+1);
   strncpy(stemp,*a,pos);
   strcpy(stemp+pos,c);
   strcat(stemp,b);
   free(a);
   *a = stemp;
   return *a;
}
```